# Create array in object in for loop. Laravel

Tags: laravel

How can I create an object inside a object inside a for loop? This is what I have, I want to be able to add another entry into this object every time the for loop happens but with an incremented number each time

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $question->rank; $i++) {
    $question->opciones = [
        'id' => $i,
        'option' => $i
    ];
}
```

I want that to look like this inside `$question`

```
{ 
   "id":4,
   "question":"question?",
   "user_id":1,
   "survey_section_id":2,
   "response_type_id":3,
   "optional":0,
   "num":null,
   "rank":6,
   "show_text":1,
   "created_at":"2019-12-10 08:22:37",
   "updated_at":"2019-12-10 08:22:37",
   "opciones":[ 
      { 
         "id":1,
         "option":1
      },
      { 
         "id":2,
         "option":2
      },
      { 
         "id":3,
         "option":3
      },
      { 
         "id":4,
         "option":4
      },
      { 
         "id":5,
         "option":5
      },
      { 
         "id":6,
         "option":6
      }
   ]
}
```

The current output is just this

```
{ 
   "id":4,
   "question":"question?",
   "user_id":1,
   "survey_section_id":2,
   "response_type_id":3,
   "optional":0,
   "num":null,
   "rank":6,
   "show_text":1,
   "created_at":"2019-12-10 08:22:37",
   "updated_at":"2019-12-10 08:22:37",
   "opciones":[ 
      { 
         "id":1,
         "option":1
      }
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the `opciones` property every time.

Replace with this to append to the array instead of overwriting it:

```php
$question->opciones[] = [
    'id' => $i,
    'option' => $i
];
```